# CSS rule to disable text selection highlighting on ol li number within contenteditable div

Tags: html, css

Given:

1. List item 1
2. List item 2

I'm trying to highlight only the content within the li

```
<div contenteditable="false">
<ol>
  <li><span>List item 1</span></li>
  <li><span>List item 2</span></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

This works fine if I apply the `-webkit-user-select: none;` to the `ol` and `-webkit-user-select: all;` to ol li span. So long as `contenteditable = false`. If I set it to true then the css no longer takes effect.

Any ideas?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/bQXFZ/

Comment: you want to highlight content within li? then why do you have it within the div block

Comment: makes no difference whether it's within a div block or not. e.g. <ol contenteditable="true"> still exhibits the same issue.